# Pass data json string to number Vue.js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to order a table by number and by words that I collect through an API, the words order them well but the numbers do not, how do I pass the value of the string to number.

this is the call I make to the API.

```js
axios.get(`/json/secciones`+ tienda +`.json`)
      .then(response => {this.userInfo = response.data;})
      .catch(e => {this.errors.push(e);});
```

and returns this to me

```css
[
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 1,
      "desc_section": "MATERIALES DE CONSTRUCCION",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": "79413.5525190617"
    },
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 2,
      "desc_section": "CARPINTERIA Y MADERA",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": "74704.3439572555"
    },
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 3,
      "desc_section": "ELECTR-FONTAN-CALOR",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": "101255.89182774"
    },
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 4,
      "desc_section": "HERRAMIENTA",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": "36969.8901028374"
    }
    ]
```

How can I get it back like this?

```css
[
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 1,
      "desc_section": "MATERIALES DE CONSTRUCCION",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": 79413.5525190617
    },
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 2,
      "desc_section": "CARPINTERIA Y MADERA",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": 74704.3439572555
    },
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 3,
      "desc_section": "ELECTR-FONTAN-CALOR",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": 101255.89182774
    },
    {
      "id_store": 2,
      "id_section": 4,
      "desc_section": "HERRAMIENTA",
      "id_rule": 1,
      "sale_potential": 36969.8901028374
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `map` function applied to the array and cast that attribute to a number using `Number()` object constructor :

```
axios.get(`/json/secciones`+ tienda +`.json`)
      .then(response => {this.userInfo = response.data.map(item=>{
                                     item.sale_potential=Number(item.sale_potential)
                                          return item;
                                      });

})
      .catch(e => {this.errors.push(e);});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's the answer, the only thing missing }) before .catch ()